# Retrieve stored logger data (Android Oreo or Pie, maybe even higher)

Tags: logging

I found an option to store logs: `Settings` -> `System` -> `Advanced` -> `Developer options` -> `Store logger data persistently on device`.

I wonder where these logs are saved and how we retrieve them. I searched online but found no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`logd` is the logging daemon on Android which mainly covers the functionality of its desktop counterpart [syslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd), but also includes [klogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/klogd) and partially [auditd](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/logd/README.auditd) to get logs from SELinux subsystem of kernel. However `logd` just reads from different memory buffers (in RAM) and doesn't save to persistent memory (files) by default. We can use commandline tools `logcat` and `log` to read/write from/to `logd` respectively. Read [here](https://elinux.org/Android_Logging_System) more about memory buffers - `main`, `system`, `radio`, `events`, and `crash`.

If one needs persistent logs as files, a separate sub-service (available on `userdebug` and `eng` builds only since Oreo <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/558282bfe4650f7b249f5ba0a24d3a400d67b78b))</sup>) named [`logcatd`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/logcat/logcatd.rc) (`logcat` daemon  which itself reads from `logd`) can save them to filesystem in **`/data/misc/logd/`** (not accessible without root). Behavior of the service on boot is controlled by properties `logd.logpersistd.enable` and `persist.logd.logpersistd` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/logd/README.property#14))</sup>. Or to manually start/stop the service shell scripts `/system/bin/logpersist.[start|stop]` can be used.

The option *“Store logger data persistently on device”* in *“Developer Options”* also controls the same service using property `persist.logd.logpersistd.buffer`. From [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#debugging):

> **Store logger data persistently on device:** Select the type of log messages you want to store persistently on the device. Options are off, all, all but radio, or kernel only.