# on Android 9 How do I get an audit going back some 10 days about a process that deleted some internal data

Tags: root-access, usb-debugging, logging

I am `magiskally rooted` on my `Android phone` running version 9 `MIUI` 11. In fact I moved to`MIUI`Just a week ago. Had This phone has a replacement of my lost AT&t phone since couple of months and initially installed custom GSI ROM which did not support many frequencies here so moved to stock.

**Problem**  
About 5 days ago my entire WhatsApp internal data the most important of which is the  `msgstore.db file` was cleaned out.

 was extremely sceptical of MIUI vis-a-vis cleanliness & privacy is concerned and was trying to figure out how to to disable certain MIUI components which I could confirm were spyware.
And then this tragedy happened.
I would like to know which process has done this. I did not disable at that time the `cleaner` app - now it's disabled.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to dig out which process cleaned out my phone I am about just a week away from when this incident happened

**What I did**  
Looked up the `logcat` but I can't beyond a few days.

 what else will tell me the story ? I have `USB debugging` enabled

Comment: Android does not have any logs beyond logcat that could be used for what you want.

Comment: But if you are prepared beforehand and it happens again, you may identify the culprit: [How to identify the app/process which re-mounts partitions R/W, creates files and changes file permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214284/218526). // Logcat persistence: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216659/218526

Comment: Thanks Irfan  for those neat n' tidy answers . `https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239500/analyzing-boot-loop-root-cause-from-console-ramoops-0-logcat`  this question carrying a `bounty` might be of intrest  if you  are   that 'colonel' of  `kernel` & help get back my `/data` working with newly installed instance