# Keep/retain a syslog at lowest level possible even after a restart

Tags: 9.0-pie, reboot, logging, hard-reset

Over the last several days, my phone suddenly started giving me a problem. It gets into a restart cycle - there is no pattern of when this problem occurs. It's very random, also the number of restarts in each instance is variable.

I did factory reset twice (including cache partition clear) and hard reset (from recovery menu)

Now I see some reduction in the problem, but it's not completely gone. It's my gut feeling it's a software issue.

Is there any way to keep debugger logs on at the sys level so that next time a problem happens and after a restart, I might get some clues?

Comment: Hi, questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic here, so I reworded it to make it acceptable. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: See [last_kmsg / pstore](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213460/218526) and [persistent logcat](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216659/218526).