# Wipe Data(Factory Reset) related logs should persist in the recovery log file right? (Stock android)

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, stock-android, logging, data

(Stock android.)

[image: zis iz fecking intentional]
"E:Cannot log to file /dev/fscklogs/log"

-Other phones don't prompt this during the data wipe(factory reset), this is fecking intentional.

Also it got no battery charging cycle count in the bug report neither.

Is there any other reliable way to determine if the phone is genuinely brand new?

Through Recovery Mode and Android Settings, Wipe Data(Factory Reset) related log entries should persist in the recovery log file under Recovery Mode right?

The related log entries should persist even after reboot, power off, wipe data(factory reset), right?

Other phones I've used will retain all wipe data related log entries.

Currently I've a brand new android phone that doesn't do that.

'Wipe data' related log entries will disappear after powering off or rebooting the device(the recovery log file still exist, and judge by the changes of the numbers inside every [ ] at the start of every line, all remained log entries are actually newly generated, though the log file's size will shrink back to the exact size before the wipe data action).

(It proceeds like this:

Go into the recovery mode;

No wipe data related entry inside the recovery log file;

Perform wipe data;

Related entries appear, the log file's size increases;

Reboot or power off then on again;

Wipe data related entries disappeared, the log file's size shrink back to before the wiping, the numbers inside every [ ] at the start of every lines have changed.)

Such shady doing, alternating the default logging behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve stored logger data (Android Oreo or Pie, maybe even higher)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216657/retrieve-stored-logger-data-android-oreo-or-pie-maybe-even-higher)// See the accepted answer

Comment: @beeshyams shouldn't the recovery log unaffected by that? Since the developer option certainly will be turned off after the wipe data(factory reset) and any alternation done through that. Also I've never needed to turn on anything for the recovery log to persist on other phones.

Comment: @beeshyams it's the wipe data related log entries are disappearing, the recovery log file itself is persisting. But judge from the changes in numbers inside '[ ]' at the start of every lines, all remaining entries are actually newly generated.

Comment: I guess another question is: what is the device model? As you may have noticed, manufacturers can and do customize their Android OS including system logging.

Comment: recovery logs are in cache partition. on factory reset usually cache partition is formatted too

Comment: I have no technical understanding. I was  only pointing to an existing answer and it looked to me that what you are asking in your question is covered there

Comment: @alecxs On me other phones the recovery log file contains multiple 'wipe complete' and related entries. Everytime I perform the wipe data(factory reset) action, one 'wipe completed' and other related entries will be added into the log file. Some of the phones even have multiple recovery log files. If what you've described holds true that wouldn't be possible, non of the wipe data(factory reset) related entries should've survived the formatting.

Comment: @alecxs And for this brand new phone, the wipe data related entries will persist before reboot or power off the phone, but after reboot or power off, the log file itself still exist just the wipe data related entries are all gone.

Comment: Other phones don't prompt this during the data wipe(factory reset), this is fecking intentional: "E:Cannot log to file /dev/fscklogs/log"

Comment: you say *"data wipe(factory reset)"* but that's two different things. on data wipe only userdata partition is wiped, while on factory reset usually userdata + metadata + cache partition is formatted (and keystore in TEE is erased). also note that a copy of current session is hold in RAM (/tmp/recovery.log for TWRP) and may saved to /cache on exit (usually rotated)

Comment: @alecxs Are you trolling pally? It's verbatim 'Wipe data'/Factory reset ' in the Recovery Mode of ely Android phone I've ever seen.
And after entering the 'Wipe data'/Factory reset', there is no other options other than confirm to execute or not. 
Here's an example: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/onda/onda-v919-3g-air-97-dual-boot/

Comment: @alecxs and the screenshot I've added at the beginning of the post clearly shows "Formatting /data" and "Formatting /metadata" when executing the wipe data action.

Comment: I apologize for confusing custom recovery with stock recovery. you are right, if you have separate entry for wipe cache partition, apparently only userdata and metadata (and keystore) is formatted on factory reset