Short logcat on Android 13+
I'm seeing a small number of logcat entries from my apps and the system, since Android 13, and now Android 14, on both my Pixel 6 Pro and Pixel 8 Pro.
I can only see entries from about 5 - 10 minutes into the past before plugging the phone in to check the logcat. If I leave it plugged in, then it doesn't clear and I can see as far back as I could when I first plugged it in. However, a lot of the time I need to check something a couple of hours after it happens while the phone was unplugged.
I have increased the log buffer size in Developer Options to 4M and then 8M and it's still the same. I should be able to see logcat entries from the previous day with such big log buffers! It's also the same whether checking the logcat from Android Studio or from the phone itself with a logcat reader app, unless I leave it open to record.
Has anyone else run into this? Anything I can do to bring this back to how it was on Android 12 and below?

Logcat is a ring buffer in RAM that can hold a specified number of entries. Therefore how much you can see messages in the past depends on the number of entries generated by Android. See developer settings to change the buffer size.

See also How do I increase the size of logcat buffers?

Hi, thanks for the answer but as stated in my question, I have already tried that.

I would recommend to read out logcat using the command line adb logcat instead of Android Studio. This way you are getting the raw output. Note that logcat showing apps are useless unless your phone is rooted. I would also recommend checking the logcat buffer size using adb logcat -g may be the UI has a bug and your changed logcat size is not correctly applied. One potential reason why the logcat is short could be that your phone crashes and reboots which erases logcat buffer. Have you set a SIM pin and or a lock screen PIN so that you recognize a reboot?

You can persist the log to file: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216659/218526
